# xpath query for dl dd not working

Tags: php, html, xpath, html-parsing

this is my code so far:

```
$htmlString = file_get_contents("http://developer.adition/rAD41126");
$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($htmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXPATH($domDocument);
$className = "phui-property-list-properties "; 
$results = $xpath->query("//dl[@class='$className']/dd[last()]" );

var_dump($results);`
```

The output is an empty `DOMNodeList` element.It should give me the last `dd` element of the html part of which is shown below. the classname `"phui-property-list-properties "` has an intentional extra space as it appears in the DOM.

The part of the DOM that has the relevant elements is

```
<dl class="phui-property-list-properties ">
   <dt class="phui-property-list-key">Project/Package Auditors </dt>
   <dd class="phui-property-list-value">
   <dt class="phui-property-list-key">Committed </dt>
   <dd class="phui-property-list-value">
   <dt class="phui-property-list-key">Parents </dt>
   <dd class="phui-property-list-value">
   <dt class="phui-property-list-key">Branches </dt>
   <dd class="phui-property-list-value">
   <dt class="phui-property-list-key">Tags </dt>
   <dd class="phui-property-list-value">
   <dt class="phui-property-list-key">Subscribers </dt>
   <dd class="phui-property-list-value">
     <em>None</em>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

I want to get the last `dd` element with attribute `class="phui-property-list-value"`

`EDIT`

I get an empty object even for the query

```
$className = "phui-property-list-properties ";
$results = $xpath->query("//dl[@class='$className']");

var_dump($results);
```

Comment: i don't think there is a problem on the query, should get that node based on the markup you gave

Comment: Your original and EDIT sections contain an extra space at the end in `$className` variable value. Try removing that. Hope it will work.

Comment: @arvinchhi the extra space exists in the DOM element and is intentional. I removed it and still it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM objects are invisible to `var_dump()` and `print_r()`. [Read Here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php#86224)

Your code works fine and also shows number of results, but `var_dump()` is not working here. Following code shows how to check the result.

```
<?php
$htmlString = <<<EOD
<dl class="phui-property-list-properties ">
   <dt class="phui-property-list-key">Project/Package Auditors </dt>
   <dd class="phui-property-list-value">
   <dt class="phui-property-list-key">Committed </dt>
   <dd class="phui-property-list-value">
   <dt class="phui-property-list-key">Parents </dt>
   <dd class="phui-property-list-value">
   <dt class="phui-property-list-key">Branches </dt>
   <dd class="phui-property-list-value">
   <dt class="phui-property-list-key">Tags </dt>
   <dd class="phui-property-list-value">
   <dt class="phui-property-list-key">Subscribers </dt>
   <dd class="phui-property-list-value">
     <em>None</em>
  </dd>
</dl>
EOD;

$domDocument = new DOMDocument();
$domDocument->loadHTML($htmlString);
$xpath = new DOMXPATH($domDocument);
$className = "phui-property-list-properties "; 
$results = $xpath->query("//dl[@class='$className']/dd[last()]" );

foreach ($results as $result) {
    $xml = $result->ownerDocument->saveXML($result);
    var_dump($xml);
}
?>
```

Output:

```
string(74) "<dd class="phui-property-list-value">&#13;
     <em>None</em>&#13;
  </dd>"
```